# Is KineticJS Polygon Deprecated

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

If you go to the [documentation for KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/docs/) the sidebar navigation doesn't have a link to the page for Polygon, but the page is [still there](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Polygon.html). Is this intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of V5 the polygon is now a line--actually a closed polyline.

If you want the equivalent of the old polygon, just set the closed property of a polyline to true.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything for me to look out for if I want to refactor my code?

Comment: Refactoring is fairly straightforward.  Change `new Kinetic.Polygon` to new `Kinetic.Line` and add the closed:true property.  Good luck with your project!